# export -f in bash isnt working as I expected at all. Cant export function to bash subprocess

Tags: bash, function, subprocess, export

here is my script, its really simple. I've been told that this is supposed to work and that this same script works for someone else. It doesn't work for me however and I cannot figure out why. I just would like to be able to define functions and make them accessible to child processes but I have been unable to get this to work after longer than I'm willing to admit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

copy() {
    notify-send "Copied"
}
export -f copy

fzf --bind "enter:execute(copy {})"
```

Its the same when I try to substitute functions that I've defined with other commands as well. It happens no matter which shell I use to run it and whether its run like

```
./fzf.sh
```

or

```
. ./fzf.sh
```

or

```
source "$HOME/path/fzf.sh" && bash -c "$HOME/path/fzf.sh"
```

I tried to add "set -x" and ran it with xtrace and just got this error:

```
addr2line: fzfclip.sh: file format not recognized
```

and the same "zsh:1:command not found" whether its called from a bash session or a zsh shell session. Im really confused here. I've also tried changing the shebang around as well to #!/bin/bash and I tried it with sh and zsh as well just to see if anything would change at all and sh obviously failed because its not defined in posix and zsh said invalid options. I didn't expect that to work in the first place but still wanted to see if there were differences in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The `execute()` action uses your default shell from the `$SHELL` environment variable. If this is `zsh` it won't inherit `bash` functions. So you need to execute the command with `bash` explicitly.

```
fzf --bind "enter:execute(bash -c 'copy {}')"
```

Another option is to set the environment variable to `bash`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash fzf --bind "enter:execute(copy {})"
```

Comment: I *think* it'd also work to override `SHELL` just for `fzf` (and its subprocesses) with `SHELL=/bin/bash fxf --bind "enter:execute(copy {})"`. But this probably won't work for commands other than `fxf` (e.g. `find -exec`).

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely the issue. Would it be a good idea to just unset the shell environment variable to avoid situations like these?

Comment: No, then it defaults to `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added that to my answer. `find -exec` doesn't use any shell (it simply calls `execvp()`), so it's moot there.